# how to add a spinner to each list item in a list view and respond to those click events?

Tags: android, spinner

how can I add a spin box to a list view item and respond to those click events? should that be implemented in the list adapter?

I would add my source code, but I'm not sure how it would help in this case... but if it does help let me know and I'll add it. any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a custom adapter with a custom item layout.
In this row layout, set your views such as : TextView and Spinner
And then in the function GetView of your custom adapter, intercept those views and do what you want.

Here is an example, do the same thing for spinner : http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429